# Script to AWS Lambda?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I have this bash script which lists all active EC2 instances across regions:

```
for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions --output text | cut -f3` do
 echo -e "\nListing Instances in region:'$region'..."
 aws ec2 describe-instances --region $region
done
```

I'd like to port this to a Lambda function on AWS. What would be the best approach today? Do I have to use a wrapper or similar? Node? I googled and found what looked like mostly workarounds.. but they were a couple of years old. Would appreciate an up-to-date indication.

Comment: This is such a tiny and simple piece of code it would probably be quicker to just rewrite it as a Python Lambda function instead of trying to get bash working in Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do it:

1. Using custom runtimes and layers: https://github.com/gkrizek/bash-lambda-layer
2. 'Exec'ing from another runtime: https://github.com/alestic/lambdash

Answer (score 1):

You should write it in a language that has an AWS SDK, such as Python.

You should also think about what the Lambda function should *do* with the output, since at the moment it just retrieves information but doesn't do anything with it.

Here's a sample AWS Lambda function:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    instance_ids = []

    # Get a list of regions    
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
    response = ec2_client.describe_regions()

    # For each region
    for region in response['Regions']:

        # Get a list of instances
        ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region['RegionName'])
        for instance in ec2_resource.instances.all():
            instance_ids.append(instance.id)

    # Return the list of instance_ids
    return instance_ids
```

Please note that it takes quite a bit of time to call all the regions sequentially. The above can take 15-20 seconds.